# "Forecast" package in R couldn't be executed

Tags: r, forecast

Previously, I had used this same package with the very same data. Today, I installed couple of neural network package in R. I noticed that after installing the new package, I can no longer execute the **"forecast"** package. There is some package missing, which I had re-install again. And the last one, I had this warning message. Is there anyone had any idea what it was?

> library(forecast)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    namespace ‘pkgconfig’ 2.0.1 is being loaded, but >= 2.0.2 is required
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘forecast’ was built under R version 3.4.4

I had try to re-install the "forecast" package but still I got some error message. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You should again install the `forecast` package using `install.packages("forecast")`. I think this should fix the problem.

Comment: I had already re-install the forecast package twice and restart the computer but it still not working. Btw, Thanks for the response @BappaDas

Answer (score 0):

By @andresrcs(Sustainer)
Jul 6
`Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
namespace ‘pkgconfig’ 2.0.1 is being loaded, but >= 2.0.2 is required`

This is telling you that you have to update this package dependency, try installing it first with

`install.packages("pkgconfig")`
If everything goes well, then you can try to install `ggplot2` again, but this time try with this command

`install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)`